# Dict to CSV with checking of Headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a long `dict` which was created by marging of lists of tuples. This `dict` contains a values from the lists- so it has a order, like

```
 value:key1, value:key2, value:key3, value:key1, value:key2, value:key3
```

But its not a rule! There are places where there is not a `key2` and places where is for example `key4`.
This `values` has a different keys.

So it look like much like this

```
 value:key1, value:key2, value:key1, value:key2, value:key4
```

I would like to create a csv file from this data. I would like to look over the `dict`, look at the keys, add these keys to csv header, if it doesn't contain that key and add value to that keys and `none` if there is not a value.

So I have this

```
{'www.example1.com': 'url', 'FAILURE TO APPEAR (FOR FELONY OFFENSE) - FELONY': 'Charge', 'SIMULTANEOUS POSSESSION OF DRUGS AND FIREARMS - FELONY': 'Offense Date', 'POSSESSION WITH INTENT TO DELIVER METHAMPHETAMINE OR COCAINE': 'Court Type', 'Count=3': 'Court Date', '10-30-2019': 'Bond', '11-16-2019': 'Charging Agency', '': 'DEGREE', '181680713': 'ID', '24': 'Age', 'H': 'Race', 'M': 'Sex', 'BRO': 'Eye Color', 'BLK': 'Hair Color', '175 lb (79 kg)': 'Weight', '5′ 10″ (1.78 m)': 'Height', 'address example': 'Address', '11/16/2019 at 22:07': 'Admit Date', 'Benton Co': 'Confining Agency', 

'www.example2.com': 'url', '32-5a-191.4': 'STATUTE', '000-0000 (ALABAMA STATE TROOPERS)': 'COURT CASE NUMBER', 'IGNITION INTERLOCK VIOLATION': 'Description', 'V': 'LEVEL', '$1000.00': 'Bond Set Amount', '181727213': 'ID', 'name example': 'Name', 'W': 'Race', 'MALE': 'Gender', 'Released': 'Inmate Status', 'some number': 'Booking No', 'some number': 'Inmate Number', '11/18/2019 at 16:49': 'Booking Date', '11/18/2019 at 20:35': 'Release Date', '33': 'Arrest Age', 'some address': 'Address Given'}
```

and I would like to have a `csv` file like this

```
         url        |      Charge    |   Statute      
1  www.example1.com     SIMULTANEOUS       none
2  www.example2.com        none         32-5a-191.4
```

order in header is not important.

I tried this code, but It overwrites data in first row, without appending...

```py
res = defaultdict(list)

d = dict((y, x) for x, y in my_dict)
for key, val in sorted(d.items()):
    res[val].append(key)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res, orient='index').fillna(np.nan).T
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: it because of Python write mode, default ‘w’. try `df.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', header=False)` for more info follow [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: thank for the tip, but it just wrote the second one(first one overwrited) for all categories, first one in new line for the `ID`, `URL` category only and then it looped over and made the same thing for the next two lines

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context for this? It’s difficult to tell exactly what you’re trying to do. See: [mcve]. Why are you sorting the contents of your dict? Your dict keys and values are swapped (or inverted?), too?

Comment: @Alexander Cécile what kind of content do you need? There is a whole `dict` variable and `code` which I'm trying to use to save it as `csv` file, I have nothing more that is connected to this problem.

Comment: the `d` variable is printed `dict` above. So they are swapped because of that `dict((y, x) for x, y in` I really dont need to swap it, if you have a good solution without swapping the values. I'm sorting it because they have to be sorted - without that sort method it is not going to fit to the right headers

Comment: @AndrejovicAndrej Where does the example dictionary you shared fit into your code?

Comment: @AndrejovicAndrej Are you the one creating the dict by the way? What rules does it follow, exactly? I think this is pretty crucial information, particularly in such an odd situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example i see every new row start with url.

I think this code can do it.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {
    'www.example1.com': 'url', 
    'FAILURE TO APPEAR (FOR FELONY OFFENSE) - FELONY': 'Charge', 
    'SIMULTANEOUS POSSESSION OF DRUGS AND FIREARMS - FELONY': 'Offense Date', 
    'POSSESSION WITH INTENT TO DELIVER METHAMPHETAMINE OR COCAINE': 'Court Type', 
    'Count=3': 'Court Date', 
    '10-30-2019': 'Bond', 
    '11-16-2019': 'Charging Agency', 
    '': 'DEGREE', 
    '181680713': 'ID', 
    '24': 'Age', 
    'H': 'Race', 
    'M': 'Sex', 
    'BRO': 'Eye Color', 
    'BLK': 'Hair Color', 
    '175 lb (79 kg)': 'Weight', 
    '5′ 10″ (1.78 m)': 'Height', 
    'address example': 'Address', 
    '11/16/2019 at 22:07': 'Admit Date', 
    'Benton Co': 'Confining Agency', 

    'www.example2.com': 'url', 
    '32-5a-191.4': 'STATUTE', 
    '000-0000 (ALABAMA STATE TROOPERS)': 'COURT CASE NUMBER', 
    'IGNITION INTERLOCK VIOLATION': 'Description', 
    'V': 'LEVEL', 
    '$1000.00': 'Bond Set Amount', 
    '181727213': 'ID', 
    'name example': 'Name', 
    'W': 'Race', 
    'MALE': 'Gender', 
    'Released': 'Inmate Status', 
    'some number': 'Booking No', 
    'some number': 'Inmate Number', 
    '11/18/2019 at 16:49': 'Booking Date', 
    '11/18/2019 at 20:35': 'Release Date', 
    '33': 'Arrest Age', 
    'some address': 'Address Given'
}

items = []

curr_dict = None

for key in my_dict.keys():
    new_key = my_dict[key]
    new_value = key if key else 'None'

    if new_key == 'url':
        curr_dict = {}
        items.append(curr_dict)

    curr_dict[new_key] = new_value

df = pd.DataFrame(items).fillna('None')
df.to_csv("file.csv", index = False)
```